# How to create multiple layer directories in gradle

Tags: gradle

I would like to create multiple layer directory with gradle. Below code not work:

```
def path = "abc/def"
new File(path).mkdirs()
```

What's proper way to do it? just like qmkdir -p abc/defq in bash shell. I know do it one by one will work but I would like code can accept any path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a full path name.  Take, for example:

```
tasks.clean.doLast {
    new File("${buildDir}/a/b/c").mkdirs()
}
```

And then the command `./gradlew clean`.  This does successfully create the tree structure in the build folder.

[image: Dir tree with a/b/c]